# how do I set the slider range in Visual Studio 2010 (for C++)?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm new to Visual Studio so this question might be trivial, but I just can't figure out how I can set slider properties. I've added a slider to my program so that the user can set a threshold that is used for some computations.

Unfortunately, the slider is fixed to return values from 0 to 100. There sure must be a way to change this default range, right?

**EDIT** I can easily set the slider range if the project is in C#.

Comment: What slider do you mean? CSliderCtrl?

Comment: I mean the "Slider Control". IDC_SLIDER1.

Comment: That seems to be an identifier, not the type of class. You mean TRACKBAR_CLASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SendDlgItemMessage(m_Dlg, IDC_SLIDER1, TBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELONG(0, 100));
```

Where IDC_SLIDER1 is the identifier.